# pass js variable to dynamic div within onclick function

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables, dynamic

This is driving me crazy, I'd welcome some guidance!

I am building dynamic div(s) that are poplulated by looping through a json array to build the div.

The div has a button that launches a modal form that I need to pass variables to. Here's the code that builds the div's:-

```
          function buildFeed(feed){


        let resultsbox = '<h3>Latest Posts</h3>';
        for(let i in feed.data){
          if(feed.data[i].message){
            var postid = feed.data[i].id;
            var title = feed.data[i].name;
            if (typeof(title) == 'undefined') {
                var title = feed.data[i].type;
            }   else {
                var title = feed.data[i].name;
            }           
            var pmsg = feed.data[i].message;
            var link_fb = feed.data[i].permalink_url;
            var link_source = feed.data[i].link;
            var pd = feed.data[i].created_time;
            var postdatetime = new Date(pd);
            var te = moment(pd).fromNow();
            var pdate = postdatetime.toLocaleDateString();
            var ptime = postdatetime.toLocaleTimeString();
            var imageresize = "https://process.filestackapi.com/werfeurweur3^7ef/resize=width:550,height:350,fit:crop,align:center/";
            var pimage = imageresize + feed.data[i].full_picture;
            var cnt_likes = feed.data[i].like.summary.total_count;
            var cnt_comments = feed.data[i].comments.summary.total_count;
            var shares = feed.data[i].shares;
            if (typeof(shares) == 'undefined') {
                var cnt_shares = 0;
            }   else {
                var cnt_shares = feed.data[i].shares.count;
            }

            ARRAY OF VARIABLES THAT I NEED FOR THE MODAL
            var modalarray = [title,pmsg,link_source];

            //REPEATABLE DIVS ARE BUILT HERE 

            resultsbox += `<div class="col-md-3">

                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <div class="media no-margin-top content-group">
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                    <div class="media-annotation mt-5"><i class="icon-watch2 position-left"></i><strong>${te}</strong> | ${pdate} ${ptime}</div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="media-left media-middle">
                                        <i class="icon-camera text-orange-300 opacity-75"></i>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <h6 class="headline">${title}</h6>
                                    <!-- tabbable -->
                                    <div class="tabbable">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-top">
                                            <li class="active">
                                                <a href="#icon-only-tab1-${postid}" title = "summary" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">
                                                    <i class="icon-menu7"></i>
                                                    <span class="visible-xs-inline-block position-right">Post Details</span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>

                                            <li class="">
                                                <a href="#icon-only-tab2-${postid}" title = "detail" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">
                                                    <i class="icon-menu9"></i>
                                                    <span class="visible-xs-inline-block position-right">Statistics</span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                <div class="tab-content">       
                                <div class="tab-pane active" id="icon-only-tab1-${postid}">
                                <div class="thumb">
                                    <img src="${pimage}" alt="">
                                    <div class="caption-overflow">
                                        <span>
                                            <a href="${link_source}" class="btn bg-orange-300 btn-rounded btn-icon" title = "Source link" target="_blank"><i class="icon-link"></i></a>
                                            <a href="${link_fb}" class="btn bg-orange-300 btn-rounded btn-icon" title = "Facebook link" target="_blank"><i class="icon-facebook2"></i></a>

//HERE'S MY PROBLEM 

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm legitRipple" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_default" onclick="createmodal([PASS ARRAY HERE])">View Post <i class="icon-play3 position-right"></i></button>

                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="postmessage">
                                    ${pmsg}
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer panel-footer-transparent">
                                                <li data-popup="tooltip" title="Engagements" class="btn heading-btn"><i class="icon-heart6 position-left"></i> ${cnt_likes}<//li>
                                                <li data-popup="tooltip" title="Comments" class="btn heading-btn"><i class="icon-comment-discussion position-left"></i> ${cnt_comments}<//li>
                                                <li data-popup="tooltip" title="Shares" class="btn heading-btn"><i class="icon-share3 position-left"></i> ${cnt_shares}<//li>
                                </div> <!-- End of footer -->
                                </DIV>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="icon-only-tab2-${postid}">
                                    ${pmsg}
                                </div>
                                </DIV>
                                </DIV>
                            </div> <!-- End of thumbnail -->
                            </div> <!-- End of BOX -->`;
          }
        }
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = resultsbox;
      }
```

I am unable to pass the modal_array to the onlick function of the modal launch button.

I have tried passing the array like this:-

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm legitRipple" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_default" onclick="createmodal(${modal_array})">View Post <i class="icon-play3 position-right"></i></button>
```

like this:-

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm legitRipple" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_default" onclick="createmodal('${modal_array}')">View Post <i class="icon-play3 position-right"></i></button>
```

like this:-

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm legitRipple" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_default" onclick="createmodal(modal_array)">View Post <i class="icon-play3 position-right"></i></button>
```

I then have the function which is trying to update the modal form like this:-

```
function createmodal(modalarray) {
document.getElementById('mod_title').innerHTML= modal_array[0];     
document.getElementById('mod_message').innerHTML= modal_array[1];       
}
```

But this is throwing errors.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong please?

Thanks

Jonathan

Comment: Try using: `${JSON.stringify(modal_array)}`

Comment: The problem that throws a Uncaught ReferenceError: modal_array is not defined becasue it is referenced with my string I think. Remember, the div is built like this resultsbox += `div stuff here etc`; which means I can't easily reference variables created outside of this. The only way I seem to be able to reference a variable is ${varname} but this isn't working with thin the onclick function - I think maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way completely

Comment: You've defined `modalarray` **NOT** `modal_array` in the above code. Here : `var modalarray = [title,pmsg,link_source];`

Comment: sorry - that was a typo - so I can now get it to pass a string with comma seperated variables from the array but I can not access modal_array[0] for the first variable, modal_array[1] for the second etc - they just return the letter or character at the position of the string

Comment: How are you passing the variables ? Can you show that code ?

Comment: I create the array like this var modal_array = [title,pmsg,link_source]; and then I pass it o the function like this onclick="createmodal('${modal_array}')" and the function is this  function createmodal(modal_array) {
 console.log(modal_array); 
 
 }

Comment: I need to access each array element in my createmodal function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148380/discussion-between-abhishekkannojia-and-jonathan-lyon).

Comment: Oh, just saw your code `createmodal(modal_array) { console.log(modal_array);}` If you are receiving the array directly then no need to use the string interpolation operator. Just pass the name like `onclick="createmodal(modal_array)"` and it should work.

Comment: it doesn't work I'm afraid; As I mentioned in my question - I have tried:-

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm legitRipple" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_default" onclick="createmodal(modal_array)">View Post <i class="icon-play3 position-right"></i></button> 
I think it's because I am creating the div within ` ` (back ticks) so I can't pass normal variables without using ${variable} but this doesn't work within an 'onclick run function with variable situation' it seems.

Comment: Maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way - in essence, I want a modal popup to show more info than I am currently showing in the main div(s) <div class="col-md-3"> <div class="thumbnail"> </div></div> that are dynamically created. Please help someone!!!!!!!!!!!!!